# Linux VXLAN Hardware offloading

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, vxlan

When looking at several guides to setup VxLAN networks on Linux there seems to be 2 options:

1. Open vSwitch (OVS)
2. Native Linux VxLAN device.

When using OVS there is an option to use vxlan encap/decap hardware offloading:

```
$ sudo ovs-vsctl set ... other_config:hw-offload=true
```

Is there a method to use vxlan encap/decap hardware offloading when using native vxlan devices?
If so, how can i enable/disable this hardware offloading and verify this?

Comment: Here's a mention: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.1/networking/device_drivers/ethernet/intel/i40e.html#vxlan-and-geneve-overlay-hw-offloading . Maybe you have to check the driver documentation of your NIC model?